# Changing drawMode with setDrawMode in Corona

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I want to change drawMode in Corona. It works only when the body is falling on the ground at the beginning. I can't change drawMode when the body is lying on the ground. Could someone help me pls? Here is the code with onKeyEvent function.

```
local physics = require "physics"

function onKeyEvent( event )

if (event.keyName == "d") then
    physics.setDrawMode( "debug" );
end

if (event.keyName == "n") then
    physics.setDrawMode( "normal" );
end

if (event.keyName == "h") then
    physics.setDrawMode( "hybrid" );
end

end

Runtime:addEventListener( "key", onKeyEvent );

physics.start();
physics.setScale( 60 )
physics.setGravity( 0, 9.8 ) -- initial gravity points downwards


local groundIm = display.newRect(0, 400, 320, 20);
groundIm:setFillColor(255, 255, 255);
local ground = physics.addBody(groundIm, "static", {friction = 0.5});

local boxIm = display.newRect(100,100,30,30);
boxIm:setFillColor(0, 0, 255);

local triangleShape = { 0,-35, 37,30, -37,30 };

local body = physics.addBody(boxIm, "dynamic", {shape = triangleShape});
```

Comment: Hello Petr, are you sure that the key events are called in the code above ?

Comment: Hello, yes I am sure:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this line of code and everything should work

```
boxIm.isSleepingAllowed = false
```

Comment: Thanks, it works now. But why doesn't it work with sleeping body? I don't see any reason why it should not.

Comment: I also think it's really weird. Really don't know why. It's like the physics stopped when all bodies slept. I think it's a bug.

Comment: Ok. Do you know if there are still some other physics bugs in Corona? (Once I read something about incorrect joints) I want to make a game and I don't want to find out too late that physics is not working properly:)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the bugs in corona physics. All I know is that the physics engine is Box2D, you can visit their forum to search for bugs http://box2d.org/forum/viewforum.php?f=4